# Stata output files in surveys

Tags: stata, survey

I have some survey data which I'm using Stata to analyze.  I want to compute means of one variable by group and save those means to a Stata file.  My code looks like this:

```
svyset [iw=wtsupp], sdrweight(repwtp1-repwtp160) vce(sdr)
svy: mean x
```

I tried

```
svy: by grp: mean x
```

but that did not work.  I could save each mean to a separate file by simply saying

```
svy: mean x if grp==1
```

but that's inefficient.  Is there a better way?

Saving results to a file like one can use SAS ODS to capture results is also a need.  I am not talking about the log here.  I need the means and the associated group.  I'm thinking

```
estimates save [path],replace
```

but I'm not sure if that will give me a Stata file or the group if I can figure out how to use by processing.

Comment: `collapse` allows `pweights` and produces a new dataset directly. Sorry, but I have no idea what that SAS incantation does.

Comment: But only in memory.  I need it on disk.  Perhaps it will be saved if I say save, replace.  In any event, I have replicate weights, so I don't think that collapse will be appropriate.  Be nice if there were a way to get the CV as well.

Comment: If you reduce your dataset to a new one, then clearly you can `save` it as well. You can `collapse` the standard deviation too and hence compute the coefficient of variation. You need to explain (to me) what you mean about replicate weights. As said, `collapse` supports `pweights`.

Comment: Replicate weights accompany data sets meant to be analyzed with `bootstrap`, `jackknife`, or `brr` (balanced repeated replications). There is a weight variable for each replicate, with value zero for observations not in the replicate and an inflated version of the original weight to make up for the zero weights. The replicate weights affect only standard errors, so Nick's `collapse` solution with probability weights will work for saving means.

Comment: "Shakespeare",  please use your real name.

Exactly which CV do you want, SD/Mean over SE/Mean?

Comment: @Steve Samuels: You and I know each other and know that we use our real names, but there is no such obligation on SO.

Comment: @Nick Cox: Thanks.  I'm grateful that William took the trouble of using an interesting nom de plume.

Comment: @William Shakespeare: Note that your `if grp==1`  line  would have produced an incorrect standard error. It should be `svy, subop(if grp==1): mean x`. For the reasons see p. 81 of the Stata 13 Survey Manual ("subpopulation estimation"). Also, `estimates store` does not save into a Stata data set, so that also wouldn't work.

Comment: looks like you're analyzing the current population survey?  if you can switch over to R, here's [the complete syntax](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/current%20population%20survey%20%28cps%29) -- see the `analysis examples` script

Answer (score 2):

**Edited 10/28**
This version contains legibility improvements and the outcome variable  and saved datasets are specified in a local macro. Therefore the analyst need not touch the `foreach` block.  Easier to write and read matrix subscript expressions are used instead of the `el` matrix function: thus `m[1,1]` instead of `el("m",1,1)`.

```
sysuse auto, clear
svyset _n
************************************************  *
* Set names of grouping variable and results data *
* set in double quotes in  the  next line.        *
* ************************************************
local yvar    mpg  // variable for mean
local gpname  "foreign"
local d_results "results"

tempvar gp
gen `gp' = `gpname'

tempname memhold
postfile `memhold'  ///
`gpname' n mean se sd using `d_results', replace

levelsof `gp', local(lg)
foreach x of local lg{
svy, subpop(if `gp'==`x'): mean `yvar'
   matrix m = e(b)
   matrix v = e(V)
   matrix a = e(V_srssub)
   matrix b = e(_N_subp)
   matrix c = e(_N)

   scalar gx  = `x'
   scalar mean = m[1,1]
   scalar sem = sqrt(v[1,1])
   scalar sd = sqrt(b[1,1]*a[1,1])
   scalar n = c[1,1]
   post `memhold' (gx) (n) (mean) (sem) (sd)
}
postclose `memhold'
use results, clear
list
```

Comment: @SteveSamuelsThis works quite well except for the sd calculation which produces a data type mismatch. I suspect this is due to the use of replicate weights altering the matrix from which sd id calculated. Also, the proper formula for se is ((4/160*sum(X-Xbar)**2)**.5 (that's summed over the 160 replicate weights), but I don't see the sum of squares in the means documentation, so I assume it will have to be calculated, right?

Comment: @SteveSamuelsMeant to add that I want CV=SEM/mean

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I'm currently using Stata 12.  I'm still not clear on where _se comes from.  Judging from the documentation it should be _error since the matrix is e(error).  And can someone explain the matrix behind the sd calculation?  I still cannot get rid of the data type mismatch.

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare For an explanation of the ereturned variance matrices,see http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/weights-and-summary-statistics/ and http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-05/msg00691.html.

Comment: Changes: Adding double quotes around the matrix names in the el statements fixes the "mismatch" errors-which didn't occur when I ran the original code.  Changing the name of the scalar "se" to "sem" fixes another problem. The name of the category variable is now set in a gpname macro. I've eliminated the need to call on the _b[ ] and _se[ ]` "underscore variables". These  are documented in the -help- for "system variables". Extracting matrix elements is done with the el() function, not with underscore variables. For the e(error) matrix see the bottom of the -help- view for the -mean- command

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler approach that creates a data set of the displayed estimation results: estimated means, standard errors, confidence limits, z statistics, and p-values. `svy: mean` is called with the `over()` option, which does away with the need for the `foreach` loop and computes standard errors appropriate for subpopulation analysis. The estimation results are contained in the returned matrix `r(table)`, which is converted by the `svmat` command to a Stata data set. While `svmat` maintains column names, it does not preserve row (group) names, so it is necessary to `merge` these in to the created data set.

```
set more off

use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/ss07ptx, clear
svyset _n [pw= pwgtp], sdrweight(pwgtp*) vce(sdr)

    ************************************************ *
    * Set name of grouping variable in double quotes *
    *  in  the  next line.                           *
    * ************************************************
local gpname  "sex"
tempvar gp
egen `gp' = group(`gpname')

preserve
tempfile t1
bys `gp': keep if _n==1
keep `gp' `gpname'
save `t1'
restore

svy: mean agep   , over(`gp')
matrix a = r(table)'
clear
qui svmat double a, names(col)
gen `gp'=_n

merge 1:1  `gp' using `t1'
keep `gpname' b se z pvalue ll ul
order `gpname'
save results, replace
list
```